# For $a, b \geq 0$, $0 < x < 1$, show $(a+b)^x \leq a^x + b^x$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

Let $a, b$ be positive real numbers. Let $0 < x < 1$. Show that 
$(a+b)^x < a^x + b^x$.

The function $f(x) = (a+b)^x -a^x - b^x$ has $f(0) = -1$, $f(1) = 0$ and it seems to be an increasing function. But I am unable to show that it is increasing function.

Comment: A demo is on https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0axazt8sqs

Comment: More generally, for any concave function $f :  \mathbb{R}_{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0) \ge 0$, you can prove that $f(a+b) \le f(a)+f(b)$ (in your case, $f:t\mapsto t^x$ is differentiable, so you can use $f'$ decreasing to prove what you need)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another way:

WLOG we may normalize with $a+b = 1$, so $a, b \in (0, 1) \implies a^x > a,\quad b^x > b$, so $a^x+b^x > a+ b = 1$.

Comment: Awesome solution.