# Inequality regarding sum of rational powers of positive real numbers

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b \ge 0$ and $\frac{m}{n} \le 1$ then $a^{\frac{m}{n}} + b^{\frac{m}{n}} \ge (a+b)^{\frac{m}{n}}$.

How to prove this inequality.

If $\frac{m}{n} = \frac{1}{2}$, I know how to prove this.

The function $f(x) = x^\frac{m}{n}, x \ge 0$ is increasing for $\frac{m}{n} \le 1$.

How can I use the above fact?

Can you help me out.

This question : [For $a, b \geq 0$, $0 < x < 1$, show $(a+b)^x \leq a^x + b^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1993528)

has an answer for $a+b = 1$.

Comment: It is wrong for $m/n > 1$

Comment: @MartinR, edited the qn